# How to scrape <br>-delimited content in a webpage with rvest?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, text-mining, rvest

Good day, StackOverflowers.

I have this piece of content:

[image: A <div> with a <p> with its content separated by <br>]

EDIT: Here it is in text form:

```
<p><b>Tu dinero /  Acciones que acaban con tu quincena</b><br><br>EVITA SOBREENDEUDARTE<br><br>POR SONIA SOTO<br><br>El día de pago llegó, pero tú simplemente no pareces emocionarte como todos los mortales, no sólo de México, sino del mundo. Si esto te pasa, sólo puede existir una razón y es que has entrado en un círculo vicioso en el cual trabajas para pagar deudas, y pides más préstamos para sobrevivir la siguiente quincena, porque esta tampoco te alcanzará.<br><br>Si ya intentaste reducir al máximo tus gastos innecesarios, pero ni así la libras, sería Interesante que pusieras atención en tus hábitos, estamos seguros que ahí puedes encontrar varios porqués a tu situación. Piggo, la plataforma de inversión y ahorro, ha detectado algunos que pueden ser la causa de que el dinero se te vaya de las manos, chécalos y modifica alguna de estas conductas.<br><br>30 POR CIENTO de tus ingresos es lo máximo que puedes comprometerán deudas, recomienda Condusef</p>
```

I am able to select this tag using the following:

```
html_node(read_html(x), "div#readMoreText > p")
```

But if I run `html_text()` what I get is the entire text without any separation between lines, like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Tu dinero /  Acciones que acaban con tu quincenaEVITASOBREENDEUDARTEPOR SONIA SOTOEl día de pago llegó, pero tú simplemente no pareces emocionarte como todos los mortales, no sólo de México, sino del mundo. Si esto te pasa, sólo puede existir una razón y es que has entrado en un círculo vicioso en el cual trabajas para pagar deudas, y pides más préstamos para sobrevivir la siguiente quincena, porque esta tampoco te alcanzará.Si ya intentaste reducir al máximo tus gastos innecesarios, pero ni así la libras, sería Interesante que pusieras atención en tus hábitos, estamos seguros que ahí puedes encontrar varios porqués a tu situación. Piggo, la plataforma de inversión y ahorro, ha detectado algunos que pueden ser la causa de que el dinero se te vaya de las manos, chécalos y modifica alguna de estas conductas.30 POR CIENTO de tus ingresos es lo máximo que puedes comprometerán deudas, recomienda Condusef"
```

Is there a way with `rvest` to extract this piece of text and have it replace tags with whitespaces instead of just removing them and making the text illegible?

Thanks.

J.

Comment: Can you post the `html` code instead a picture of the code?

Comment: Edited to add the HTML chunk in code form.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the 'piping' replication which I find more intuitive:

```
library(rvest)
read_html("Somewebpage.html") %>%
 html_nodes(., "div#readMoreText > p") %>%
 gsub(pattern = '<.*?>', replacement = "|"., )
```

Splitting the nodes by an appropriate pipe (|) delimiter will help you when there are a lot things you are extracting

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, I managed to do this with the following:

```
gsub(pattern = '<.*?>', replacement = ' ', html_nodes(read_html(x), "div#readMoreText > p"))
```

Thought `html_nodes()` only returned pointers, but as it turns out, it can return text for gsub or other functions to process.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `html_text2()` that does html-like 'rendering' of text and will convert all `<br>`  into `\n`

```
library(rvest)
read_html("Somewebpage.html") %>%
 html_nodes("div#readMoreText > p") %>%
 html_text2()
```